# post->post_content filter

Tags: filters, the-content, regex

I'm trying to determine if the REGEX I'm using is incorrect -- or if I'm missing something basic here. The following:

```
add_filter('the_content','wpdu_image_replace');
function wpdu_image_replace($content) {
    global $post;
    preg_replace( '/<img.*src="(.*?)".*?>/', '<a href="\1">Image file</a>', $post->post_content );

    return $content;
}
```

should look for any `<img>` within `post->post_content` (the post's content) and replace the entire tag with an `href` that simply links to the image file. In the end what I'm going to do with this is a bit more complex -- but I figured I'd start with the basics. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [`preg_replace`](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function incorrectly. This function returns replaced content:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpdu_image_replace' );
function wpdu_image_replace( $content ) {
    return preg_replace( '/<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>/', '<a href="$1">Image file</a>', $content );
}
```

Also pay attention that you don't have to use global variable `$post`, because content of the post is passed to your function as first argument.